# Этимология слова "месяц"

Tags: этимология

Ясно, что слово "Луна" не русское. А вот как насчет "месяца"? И почему (знаю, что не любят тут вопрос "почему)))) словом "месяц" в итоге стали обозначать ущербную или растущую Луну, а словом "Луна" — или полнолуние, или непосредственно планету?

Comment: Технически, Луна - не планета.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ясно, что слово "Луна" не русское. А вот как насчет "месяца"?

И *луна* и *месяц* - это исконно русские слова. Слова очень древние, они были ещё в праславянском языке. И похожие слова существовали ещё в праиндоевропейском языке.

Вы встретили слово *луна*, наверное, в каком-то из романских языков. Их предок - латынь. Там, в латин. языке, *луна* и *месяц* - это соответственно *luna* и *mensis*.

- - 

Любопытно, что не только слово "луна", но и слово "месяц" похожи в латыни и в русском.
Есть вариант произношения латинского слова "mensis" без "n", что звучит как "мЭсис". Похоже на совр. русское  "месяц".
( [Подтверждение, на англ.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensis#Latin)
Allen, W. Sidney. 1978. VOX LATINA - The Pronunciation Of Classical Latin. Cambridge University Press.)

- - 

Слово "луна" происходит от праиндоевропейского корня *lewk- белый, светлый, сияющий.
От того же древнего корня,  например, латинское слово lux (люкс) - свет. Староирландское luchair - сияние. Славянское луч. Греческое λευκός  (leukós) - яркий, сияющий, белый. Древнеанглийское leoht (леохт) - свет, откуда совр. англ. light. А также есть другие слова, происходящие от того же праиндоевропейского (или сокр. ПИЕ) корня.

**Итак, *луна* - это, по-видимому, *сияющая*. Отсюда и будем исходить в разнице употребления слов "луна" и "месяц".**

Дальше разберём этимологию слова "месяц".
Происходит от праиндоевропейского корня mēns-. Что означает, как тот месяц, который на небе, так и месяц, как отрезок времени. То есть эти 2 значения слова "месяц", очень древние.
mēns- возможно происходит от ПИЕ корня meh-, что означает измерять. От того же ПИЕ корня (meh-) происходит, например, русское МЕра. Или англ. *measure*, через латинское *mensura*, приблизительно с тем же значением - *мера*

В ответ на Ваш вопрос, **Amarie**, могу предположить следующее. **МЕсяц - слово практическое**, для изМЕрения времени, очевидно. Молодой месяц, старый месяц. На небе, чаще всего мы видим не весь лунный диск, а только его части. Эти части соответствуют какому-то времени. Вот для этого используется слово *месяц*.

**А *луна* - слово поэтическое**. :-) Она ЛУчистая и сияющая. А когда она наиболее сияющая? Когда полная.

Answer (score 3):

> (знаю, что не любят тут вопрос "почему))))

Как раз чересчур любят. И задают его по любому поводу, даже тогда, когда такая постановка очевидно неприменима.

> Ясно, что слово "Луна" не русское.

Что считать русским? Во всяком случае, как было сказано, оба слова очень древние.

> И почему словом "месяц" в итоге стали обозначать ущербную или растущую Луну, а словом "Луна" — или полнолуние, или непосредственно планету?

Это не так. "Месяц" и "луна" в равной степени относится ко всем фазам Луны. В какой-то среде действительно так принято, что месяц - это неполная луна (что можно считать следствием общего закона разделения значений синонимов), но это очень локальное явление.
А вот почему именно так... Здесь-то такой вопрос уместен, поскольку ответ действительно предполагает причинно-следственную связь. Вот ответить на него непросто. Но можно предположить, что не в последнюю очередь сказалось календарное значение слова месяц. За календарем действительно следили по фазам Луны, т.е. месяца. 
А вот когда интересовались самой Луной, вне связи с фазами, то и слово Луна использовали.
Термины ущербная и растущая Луна - более поздние, это уже астрономы ввели. Раньше были молодой и старый (убывающий) Месяц.

Comment: begemotus, я настоятельно прошу Вас уяснить, что тут не конференция филологов. Сюда приходят самые разные люди самого разного уровня подготовки. И ХВАТИТ УЖЕ ПРИДИРАТЬСЯ К ВОПРОСУ "ПОЧЕМУ"!!! Если человек спрашивает, значит, ему интересно, значит, небезразличен русский язык!! И этот человек ПОНЯТИЯ НЕ ИМЕЕТ, можно тут говорить "почему" или нет! ХВАТИТ УЖЕ ОТПУГИВАТЬ ОТ ФОРУМА НОВЫХ УЧАСТНИКОВ!!!  
С надеждой на понимание,  
администратор.

Answer (score 0):

Луна - от ПИЕ ***louksna̯*** "светящая" (родственное слово - луч).

Месяц - от ПИЕ ***mee̯nsos***. Буквально "то, чем меряют, единица измерения". Родственные слова - мера, метка.

Answer (score -1):

Словесность в Европе и России возникла из древнееврейского (иврита). Полная луна на иврите называется «лавана»,что в переводе значит «белая». Слово «месяц» возможно возникло путем транслитерации слов «шем» - (имя),прочитано наоборот, как в иврите и «яц» - эт , значит «время»